# F# inherit interface

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I have the following class in F# that inherits Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IIdentityValidator interface:

```
type MyValidation() =
    inherit IIdentityValidator<string> with
        member x.ValidateAsync (value:string) : Task<IdentityResult> =
        .....
```

I am getting this error:

```
 This 'inherit' declaration specifies the inherited type but no arguments. Consider supplying arguments, e.g. 'inherit BaseType(args)'.
```

Why and how do I fix it?

Comment: I point out that Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IIdentityValidator does not belong to C#.

Comment: It belongs to ASP.NET?

Comment: That would be a better way of describing it.

Comment: edited question to fix that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword `inherit` is just for derived classes. You need to use `interface`:

```
type MyValidation() =
    interface IIdentityValidator<string> with
        member x.ValidateAsync (value:string) : Task<IdentityResult> =
            ...
```